# How to make the value in the textbox uneditable

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
<div class="display-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer) %>
</div>
<div class="display-label">
    <%: Html.TextBox("Customer") %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Customer) %>
</div>
```

i want this value in the textbox to be Uneditable and i still want it to be acessed in the controller. as i am passing the value there

public ActionResult Create(string Customer)

when am passing it in the label, the error " object is not set to instance" is showing up

here is the post method

```
 public ActionResult Create(string Customer,string UserName, string Password, string FirstName, string LastName,
        string MiddleInitial,  string Email,string Telephone,  bool IsAdmin, bool IsSubAdmin)
    {
        UserDAL userDALObject = new UserDAL();
        tblUser newUser = new tblUser();

        newUser.Customer =Customer ; 
        newUser.UserName = UserName;
        newUser.Password = Password;
        newUser.FirstName = FirstName;
        newUser.LastName = LastName;
        newUser.MiddleInitial = MiddleInitial;
        newUser.Email = Email;
        newUser.Telephone = Telephone; 

        newUser.IsAdmin = IsAdmin;
        newUser.IsSubAdmin = IsSubAdmin;

        userDALObject.AddUserDetails(newUser);
        TempData["UserCreationMsg"] = string.Format("User named :{0}, is created",UserName);
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<%=Html.TextBox("Customer", Model.Customer, new { @readonly = "readonly" }) %>
```

Comment: do i still get the value Model.Customer in the Textbox?

Comment: Can you post what your controller method looks like? You might be passing a null to the View

Comment: ooooh, so it's throwing a null on the Post? Can you post the entire Exception and the code for the action method you're posting to?

Comment: where does it throw that null reference?

Comment: if i show the CustomerNo in the label can i access it in my controller ??? if so can u show me how to do it using label

Comment: Null reference is thrown in view. At the <%:Html:textbox%> line

Comment: If you just want to show the user the text why do you want to put it in a TextBox? For consistency?